# Does server clustering increase througput?

Tags: cluster

I heard from a not technical person that combining two server(clustering) he can get more powerful server. He claims that then his computation take less time.

Mainly, the person is from chemistry background. He uses [Gaussian](http://gaussian.com/g16main/) program in his server.

Comment: ServerFault isn't the best place to explain such basic software design concepts, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing provides some background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Gaussian, but if it allows you to configure cluster options to share work across all servers within the cluster then yes.

In theory, clustering two servers together (and properly sharing the work between them) would cut the computation time in half, and if you keep adding more servers then it would take less time for each server.

The main reason for this speed increase is that the 
work is being done in parallel instead of sequentially.